# NUXT how to pass data from page to layout

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am creating a very simple website. I want to change the Navbar elements depending on data set in `navLayout` on the page template. I want to pass the data to the layout, then use `props` to send it to the `NavBar`. My issue is how to `emit` data from the page to the layout.

**layouts/default.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <NavBar />
    <div class="site-container">
      <nuxt />
    </div>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import NavBar from '~/components/NavBar.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    NavBar,
  }
}
</script>
```

**pages/index.vue**

```
...
<script>
export default {

  data: () => {
    return {
      navLayout: 'simple'
    }
  },
  computed: () => {
    return {
    this.$emit('navLayout', value)
    }

  }
...
</script>
```

Comment: You wanna do it depending on the route or depending on some state inside of a page?

Comment: Depending on a state within the page.

Comment: I do have this issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One option is to use vuex for that.

First go into the store folder in your nuxt project and create a `index.js` file

```
export const state = () => ({
   layout: 'Your default value',
})
    
export const mutations = {
  CHANGE_NAV_LAYOUT(state, layout) {
    state.layout = layout;
  }
}
```

Then inside any page/component you can call `this.$store.commit('CHANGE_NAV_LAYOUT',value)`

For your navbar component you create a computed property and refer it to the store layout value:

```
computed: {
     navLayout() {
         return this.$store.state.layout;
     }
}
```

Comment: Where do I place ` this.$store.commit('CHANGE_NAV_LAYOUT',value)` within a page/component?

Comment: I added it inside `created()` . But now the default is always overwritten

Comment: Their seems to be a slight delay also for when the store value is updated during from a component on a page. Would it be better to pass the value up from the component to the page then change the $store. ?

Comment: @Simon should not make any difference, I assume the delay is caused by something else

Comment: I think the delay is caused because of the way the DOM is rendered.

Comment: Can we agree on the fact that this is very hacky? I'm surprised such API doesn't exist in nuxt yet.

Answer (score 4):

You should use $emit from parent element, so the parent element to the page is layout page. Here is sample:

```
this.$parent.$emit("eventName");
```

Then listen action at layout on the Nuxt component.

```
<Nuxt @eventname="actionHandler()"/>
```

And here it is)